# How to narrow in on text in beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find the river level [here](https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/station/8208). [Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64260194/5453261) I got some amazing [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64260194/5453261) to use the first BOLD (strong) text, however today that isn't working because new strong text has appeared BEFORE the river level due to the river being in flood. Is there a way in beautiful soup to harvest the first word in bold ending with an **m** ?

Cheers!!

Comment: suggest you to add the code in this post

Comment: Running the previous code I still get `0.66m`

Comment: @daneee Check out my answer.

Comment: @MendelG But it doesn't work with the new url that the OP has provided. It prints out ```Flooding is possible - Be prepared``` for the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/station/8208'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

header = soup.find('header',class_ = "intro")

paragraphs = header.find_all('p')

txt = paragraphs[1].strong.text

print(txt)
```

Output:

```
1.97m
```

This also works for the [url](https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/station/8108) that u mentioned in ur previous question.

Output for that url:

```
0.66m
```

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a CSS Selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/station/8208'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('.intro p strong:nth-of-type(1)').text)
```

Output:

```
1.97m
```

Comment: Going with this one because sadly the one @sushil kindly provided stopped working today - I presume because the river level dropped and the formatting on the page stopped working. I wonder if the same thing will happen to this one when the river is in flood again... Thanks both OP and @sushil!!